# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, soap-client

I am using a web-hosting company's web-service (SSD India).
I am getting am `ERROR LOG` when i run my `PHP` code.
Error :
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found`

I have installed SOAP in the web-service.But i am still getting this error. 
**I cannot access any file `php.ini` as the server is not hosted in my computer and the hosting company might not allow to do this.** 
[image]

I have access to a folder named `PHP` in my `home directory` which looks something like this. I can edit any files here.**But again i cant find `php.ini` here.**

[image]

When i do `var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());`

I get this :

`array(49) { [0]=> string(4) "Core" [1]=> string(4) "date" [2]=> string(4) "ereg" [3]=> string(6) "libxml" [4]=> string(7) "openssl" [5]=> string(4) "pcre" [6]=> string(7) "sqlite3" [7]=> string(4) "zlib" [8]=> string(6) "bcmath" [9]=> string(8) "calendar" [10]=> string(5) "ctype" [11]=> string(4) "curl" [12]=> string(3) "dom" [13]=> string(4) "hash" [14]=> string(6) "filter" [15]=> string(3) "ftp" [16]=> string(2) "gd" [17]=> string(7) "gettext" [18]=> string(3) "SPL" [19]=> string(5) "iconv" [20]=> string(7) "session" [21]=> string(4) "json" [22]=> string(8) "mbstring" [23]=> string(6) "mcrypt" [24]=> string(8) "standard" [25]=> string(5) "mysql" [26]=> string(6) "mysqli" [27]=> string(7) "mysqlnd" [28]=> string(4) "Phar" [29]=> string(5) "posix" [30]=> string(10) "Reflection" [31]=> string(4) "imap" [32]=> string(9) "SimpleXML" [33]=> string(7) "sockets" [34]=> string(4) "exif" [35]=> string(9) "tokenizer" [36]=> string(3) "xml" [37]=> string(9) "xmlreader" [38]=> string(9) "xmlwriter" [39]=> string(3) "zip" [40]=> string(8) "cgi-fcgi" [41]=> string(7) "suhosin" [42]=> string(3) "PDO" [43]=> string(10) "pdo_sqlite" [44]=> string(9) "pdo_mysql" [45]=> string(7) "imagick" [46]=> string(10) "magickwand" [47]=> string(14) "ionCube Loader" [48]=> string(17) "Zend Guard Loader" }`

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists).

Comment: @iFarbod Its returning FALSE...when i execute the class_exists('SoapClient') function

Comment: Try `var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());`

Comment: @iFarbod the web-server doesnt semm to have the SoapClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do code-wise. You need to contact the server host and have them install the SoapClient extension on the box and re-compile/restart.

Comment: but see my 1st image...i have installed Soap...which can be clearly seen

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, SOAP needs to be enabled. It doesn't just install and work. It means the server has to be restarted with flags. Read more at the official docs: http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

First check the `phpinfo();` fucntion to get the active extensions, if is not defined, some server allow you set your on php.ini in your root directory.

Create a php.ini with `extension=php_soap.dll` or `extension=php_soap.so` thats depend of your server's SO then try again the `phpinfo();`.

Theres another way to active php extentions with the htaccess file, create one .htaccess with or add the `php_extension soap.so` to file.

Comment: ^ did wat u told...but not working...also when i try to make a .htaccess file it show file alredy exists and its hidden so i cannot edit it

Comment: Did you try access to the files with Filezilla ftp client? this ftp client show the hidden files. If this not work for you then I suggest to contact the support team of your server.